# Proper Allocation and Deallocation of a 2d array of Pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, 2d

Basically I am writing an RPG game which has a parent type of object called 'Piece' which represents a piece or object on the map. The Map class has a 2d array of pointers to these Piece objects and it is declared in the Map.h header file as:

```
Piece *** level;
```

And when the map class is called with a parameter with the directory of the map to load, it loads the map file and gets its dimensions. It gets the height and width of the map to allocate. In my level array I want to treat it like this level[x][y] where x is an x coord on the map and y is a y coord on the map. I have done the allocation like this:

```
level = new Piece**[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    level[i] = new Piece*[height];
}
```

I also initialize all elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        level[k][i] = 0;
```

Now my game works as it should, however I have no idea how to deallocate the level array so it causes a memory leak. I have tried deallocation like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        if (level[k][i] != 0)
            delete level[k][i];
```

I have tried the above code but to no avail.

Please help me I do not know how to deallocate this 2d array of pointers, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to be a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)?

Comment: I ain't touching 3 star code at all.

Comment: @BartoszKP +1 for that link ! And for OP: there's very, very, very few chances that your code need a triple pointer like that. Use vectors, and references (or smart pointers).

Comment: because Piece is a parents to many derived classes the only way to have the different types in a level is either a 2d array of pointers or a 2d array of references.. Can someone suggest how to get this to work with references?

Comment: If the height is fixed you could [linearize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678938/linear-simulation-of-multidimensional-array) the 2D array to a 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<shared_ptr<Piece>>> game_map(Y, vector<shared_ptr<Piece>>(X));
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        // notice position of x and y
        game_map[Y][X] = make_shared<Piece>(); // or replace Piece with derived type
    }
}
```

No need to delete anything.