# Android Development : Don't understand for each loop with 2d array

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I came across this code in a tutorial for creating a simple tic tac toe game. The complete code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/NgdUnPGg)

what does this for loop and if do? Does the `[0],[1],[2]` increment itself when the for loop loops? If a 2d array is being convert into 1d array what will it look like? Does it maintain the same position?

e.g

```
int[][] winningStates = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

if converted into 1d array will be like this?:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,0,4,8,2,4,6};
```

---

```
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
int[][] winningStates = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
boolean gameIsActive = true;

for(int[] winningState : winningStates){
            if(gameState[winningState[0]] == gameState[winningState[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningState[1]] == gameState[winningState[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningState[0]] != 2){
                gameIsActive = false;
                String winner = "Black";

                if(gameState[winningState[0]] == 0){
                    winner = "Red";
                }
                //someone has won!
                playAgainMessage again = new playAgainMessage();
                again.playAgainMethod(winner + " has Won !!");
            }
```

Comment: great! But, what's the question?

Comment: The question is in the code's comment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the for loop will generate the following values for winningState (it iterates within an array of arrays):

```
{0,1,2} -> winningState[0] = 0, winningState[1] = 1, winningState[2] = 2
{3,4,5} -> winningState[0] = 3, winningState[1] = 4, winningState[2] = 5
{6,7,8}
{0,3,6} -> winningState[0] = 0, winningState[1] = 3, winningState[2] = 6
{1,4,7}
{2,5,8}
{0,4,8}
{2,4,6}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clears out a bit of my confusion, but, isn't that we've converted the 2d array into 1d array?

Comment: You can say that, but 2D->1D (or more general, nD->1D) means making it linear like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678938/linear-simulation-of-multidimensional-array)